# Hibernate Transaction Management Comparison

Tags: java, r, hibernate, jpa, transactions

By referring to T1 and T2, which one is correct practice in creating the hibernate transaction? I have a doubt in choosing one of them.
My question is in what situation should I code like T1 or T2.

T1

```
try{
    currentSession.beginTransaction();

    // assume assume this method is a hql select query
    Person person=personService.findPerson(personId);

    // complex rules that will affect performance
    Health health=healthService.calculateComplexBizRules(personId);

    person.setHealth(health);
    currentSession.commitTransaction();
}catch (Exception e) {
   rollBackTransaction();
   e.printStackTrace();
   throw e;
}
```

T2

```
try{
   currentSession.beginTransaction();

   // assume this method is a hql select query
   Person person=personService.findPerson(personId);
   currentSession.commitTransaction();

   // complex rules that will affect performance
   Health health=healthService.calculateComplexBizRules(personId);

   currentSession.beginTransaction();
   currentSession.persist(health);
   Person person=currentSession.merge(person);
   person.setHealth(health);
   currentSession.commitTransaction();
}catch (Exception e) {
   rollBackTransaction();
   e.printStackTrace();
   throw e;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** If **Optimistic Locking** is used, in both cases the `Person` is retrieved before a complex operation. This means that upon commit if a version of the database is higher than the one originally retrieved you will get `OptimisticLockException` from which you need to recover (usually by repeating the operation after a merge). This will be the case for `T1` and `T2` option. You need to decide which one based on a study of how the system behaves here and make appropriate judgement (T2 opens and closes the second transaction which increases the total execution time and does not add any extra benefit in this case).

**2)** If you need to use **Pessimistic Locking**, meaning physically lock rows on the database once the complex operation is finished, then you need to go for T1. This might be a bottleneck of course if your `Person` might be queried many times per second though.

Answer (score 1):

T1 is all or nothing.

So if the healthSerivce would throw an exception you can rollback (or it automatically rollbacks depending on then application framework) the transaction.

For T2 depending on the underlying Database the transaction with find will not create a transaction on the database level (for example with Oracle). So the first transaction is useless anyway.

If you are using an application framework like Jakarta EE (former J2EE/Java EE) or Spring you will have the transaction boundaries declarative an most likely it will look like T1.

If the you have very high load you may go for T2 to keep transactions short.

To conclude: it depends on your use case

Comment: Think about a scenario that you need to save `Person` and `Health` at the same time just like you have given both T1 and T2 scenarios. What if an exception occurred when you persist `Health` object after saving the `Person` successfully. If your `Person` can't exist without the `Health`, now you have orphaned entry which is kind of corrupted. Similar thing could happen with T2 scenario, because you're committing the transaction each time. But in T1, `Person` has not been committed yet until `Health` successfully saved. So, as Simon said, it's really depends on your requirement.

Comment: Aren't both also all or nothing? In T2, the code can be wrapped by a try catch, and rollback the transaction if there is an exception occurred. We are using J2EE, and I always practice T1. From what I can see from T2, it tends to create multiple transactions for queries, biz rules calculation and prepare objects, at the final end, one last transaction for commit changes (e.g. merge(), saveOrUpdate()).

Comment: With T2 you have to control the transactions yourself with T1 you can use an EJB that is by default transactional or a CDI bean with @Transactional annotatoin